# Prove that $\liminf_{n\to\infty}A_n\in\mathcal A$ and $\limsup_{n\to\infty}A_n\in\mathcal A$

Tags: measure-theory, probability-theory

Let $\mathcal A$ be a $\sigma$-a;gebra. Prove that if, for all $n \in \mathcal N, A_n \in \mathcal A,$ then $\liminf_{n\to\infty}A_n\in\mathcal A$ and $\limsup_{n\to\infty}A_n\in\mathcal A$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $\mathcal A$ is a $\sigma$- algebra, we know it is closed under countable intersections.

Let $\displaystyle Q_n=\cap_{m\geq n}A_{m}\in \mathcal A\forall n$. Then:

$\displaystyle \liminf_{n\to\infty} A_n = \cup_{n=1}^{\infty}Q_n\Rightarrow\liminf_{n\to\infty}A_n\in\mathcal A$.

We also know $\mathcal A$ is closed under taking compliments. Using De Morgan's

law,

$\displaystyle \limsup_{n\to\infty}A_n=\left(\liminf_{n\to\infty}A^{c}_n\right)^{c}\Rightarrow \limsup_{n\to\infty}A_n\in\mathcal A$. $\blacksquare$

Comment: One also needs closedness under countable unions.